# Django rest_framework IsAdminUser not behaving

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `viewset` in rest framework that is not behaving like I would expect. If I login with a non-staff user and navigate to the api-url/users I can see all the users listed there.

The `IsAuthenticated` permission is working, because if I logout I get an error saying that I am not authenticated.

Am I using these permissions wrong? I have done the tutorial and looked through the docs, but I can't find anything to tell me why this shouldn't work

views:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Viewset for viewing users. Only to be used by admins"""
    queryset = LangaLangUserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = '__all__'
    permissions_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser, )

class LanguageViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """Viewset for Language objects, use the proper HTTP methods to modify them"""
    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = '__all__'
    permissions_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
```

urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'language', views.LanguageViewSet)
```

serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for User objects"""
    class Meta:
        model = LangaLangUserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the Language model"""
    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo!

It's [`permission_classes`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/), not `permissions_classes`.

---

About this part:

> The IsAuthenticated permission is working, because if I logout I cget an error saysing that I am not authenticated.

I'm not sure why this is happening but I'd blame `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` in your Django settings - maybe you have `IsAuthenticated` specified there?