# Django rest IsAdminUser not applied

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have following in my views.py ,

```
from webapi.models import members
from rest_framework import permissions
from webapi.serializers import MemberSerializer
from rest_framework import generics



class MemberList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = members.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    permission_class = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)


class MemberCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = members.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    permission_class = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
         serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

In the above IsAuthenticated is working fine fine, but when i use "permissions.IsAdminUser" for MemberCreate class it is allowing not admin user also to create items.

As per the question "[Django rest_framework IsAdminUser not behaving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434937/django-rest-framework-isadminuser-not-behaving)" I even tried to add the following in settings.py but still override is not happening,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
 }
```

No matter If Add or don't add the REST_FRAMEWORK in settings.py IsAdminUser permissions is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is with the `permission_class`

it will be

```
 permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser, )
 #              ^^^^^
```